# Rhapsody Plugin in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, rhapsody

I am trying create a plugin of Rhapsody using Visual Studio (C#) , but cannot create it. I found two options to my problem [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21411455), but none work.

I am using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using rhapsody;

public class Class1: IRPInternalOEMPlugin {

    public int ActiveProjectAboutToChange() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int ActiveProjectHasChanged() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public string OnMenuItemSelect(string menuItem) {

        RPApplication rpy = (RPApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Rhapsody.Application");
        rpProject proj;
        proj = rpy.activeProject();
        proj.addPackage("PackageTest");
        return "Success";
    }


    public string OnMenuItemSelectWithParameters(string menuItem, string parameters) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public int RhapPluginAnimationStopped() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public int RhpPluginAnimationStarted() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public int RhpPluginCleanup() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public void RhpPluginDoCommand(string theCommand) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public int RhpPluginFinalCleanup() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int RhpPluginInit() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public int RhpPluginInvokeItem() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public void RhpPluginOnIDEBuildDone(string buildStatus) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int RhpPluginSetApplication(RPApplication pRPApp) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public int RhpSavingProject() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Rhapsody doesn't give me any error. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

hmm

the documented and "official" way to develop rhapsody plugins is using Java. You can find lot of documentation about this on IBM help site.

In your case, the error message can be easily debugged in Java with Try/catch.

I had colleagues that also used C# but got mixed results.

I strongly suggest that if you don't have major constraints, to switch to Java and move on plugin development.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a plug-in?  You can access Rhapsody from C# via COM:

```
using rhapsody;

//...

RPApplication application = (RPApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Rhapsody.Application");
RPProject project = application.activeProject();
RPCollection allElements = project.getNestedElementsRecursive();

foreach (RPModelElement element in allElements)
{
    //do something
}
```